# gwt developer console running outofmemory right away

Tags: gwt, intellij-idea, smartgwt

been using the gwt plugin in eclipse for about a year, has worked pretty fine.
However, i recently upgraded to OSX lion, and i also upgraded intellij to latest version.

Now, i have a standard gwt project. I have historically been able to start it with the devconsole, change stuff and reload page in firefox. (using firefox5 currently)

But now, i can only start it, but as soon as i reload page, devconsole crashed. Yesterday it just hung, this morning i upgraded to GWT2.4 and now i just get permgen space outofmemory on first reload. I have the memory settings set to 1024m!

If someone could give me pointers it would me much appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question since i've found well, not an answer but a workaround.

In intellij, i changed the agent (only using one in development to speed things up) from gecko1_8 to safari, and used chrome.

As i mentioned, the console crashed in firefox on every reload, in Chrome i'm at 30 page reloads/recompiles and not a single console crash!

It also recompiles faster than in FF.

Have no idea why it works so crappy in FF though...

Answer (score 0):

I experienced that same issue after upgrading to Lion. I believe it has something to do with the memory management of OSX, not Eclipse or GWT. It was a source of huge inconvenience to me, and the benefits of the Lion upgrade weren't enough to justify dealing with an impaired capacity for development, so I rolled back to Snow Leopard. That resolved the problem.

I've since tried (unsuccessfully) going back to Lion and using different browser combinations, including Safari and Chrome, but Firefox still seems to be the best choice if you're using Lion- Chrome is exceptionally slow with GWT (oddly), and Webkit in general seems to not support some of the features GWT offers, so Safari's out.

I say go back to Snow Leopard, unless there's something preventing you from doing so. Good luck, and please keep us updated if you figure out a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it - just add `-XX:MaxPermSize=384m` for jvm.

Comment: I did do that, but it doesn't explain the huge difference in performance between FF and Chrome...